# Fetching data from xml Using Xquery with starts with function

Tags: java, xml, xquery

I want to fetch a data from xml Using Xquery with starts with function.

data.xml

```
              <data><employee id=\"1\"><name value=\"vA-12\">A</name> <title id=\"2\">Manager</title></employee>
                    <employee id=\"2\"><name value=\"vC-12\">C</name><title id=\"2\">Manager</title></employee>
                    <employee id=\"2\"><name value=\"vB-12\">B</name><title id=\"2\">Manager</title></employee>
             </data>
```

Now I want to fetch that name which has employee@id=title@id and name@value starts with 'vC'.

I have written this xquery for the same.Please see below but getting error-

```
for $x in /data/employee where $x/@id=$x/title/@id and [fn:starts-with($x/name/@value,vC)] return data($x/name)
```

this is error-

```
    Error on line 1 column 55 
  XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #.../title/@id and [fn:starts-with#:
    Unexpected token "[" in path expression
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Unexpected token "[" in path expression
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XQueryCompiler.compile(XQueryCompiler.java:544)
    at Xml.process(Xml.java:46)
    at Xml.main(Xml.java:30)
Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unexpected token "[" in path expression
    at net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.grumble(XQueryParser.java:479)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:221)
```

Comment: @Andrew added error pls see above

Comment: is your xml not well-formatted (escapes in attribute values)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`starts-with()` function expects two parameters. I'm not familiar with Saxon specifically, but in general xquery you can do this way :

```
for $x in /data/employee[@id=title/@id and name[starts-with(@value,'vC')]] 
return data($x/name)
```

or using `where` clause instead of predicate in `for` clause, as in your attempted query :

```
for $x in /data/employee
where $x/@id=$x/title/@id and $x/name/starts-with(@value,'vC')
return data($x/name)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just use this shorter and simpler XPath 2.0 one-liner**:

```
/*/employee[@id eq title/@id and starts-with(name/@value, 'vC')]/data(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact requirements, you might need this instead (I let you go through the differences, but basically it selects all names with `@value` starting with `vC`, where the other solutions here select all names of all employees with at least a name starting with `vC`):

```
/data/employee[@id eq title/@id]/name[starts-with(@value, 'vC')]/data(.)
```